Framer animations in nextjs inview always true
I am trying to use Framer.com React in NextJS both latest versions.
When I use the isInView hook, it's triggered when scrolling from bottom and up, but not from top and down. From top to down, it's always true (I guess it shouldn't be, because the header element is visible and not the SlideInEffect component).
Here is what I have tried:
import { useInView } from "framer-motion";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function SlideInEffect({ children }: any) {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const isInView = useInView(ref, { once: true });

    console.log("isInView:", isInView);

    return (
        <div ref={ref}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}

export default function page() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="w-full h-screen">
                header element
            </div>
            <SlideInEffect>
                <div className="text-center py-24 font-light max-w-4xl mx-auto content-text">
                    <p>
                        some content
                    </p>
                </div>
            </SlideInEffect>
            <div>
                Some other content
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

